# Problema al compilar con Angular

Tags: angular, compilar, build

Al ejecutar `ng build --prod` en angular me sale este error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec.js 1:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:3)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

¿A qué se debe esto? Ya actualicé Angular CLI global y actualicé todas las dependencias de mi proyecto. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es posible que aguna dependencia (node module) esté corrupta, yo intentaría  borrar todo el directorio node_modules del proyecto y ejecutar `npm install` para descargarlos de nuevo

Comment: Revisa tambien en lugares donde estes usando expresiones regulares (RegExp). Es posible que tengas alguna mal formateada.

Comment: Ya resolvi. El problema era en el archivo es.regexp.exec.js q estaba corrupto (tenia caracteres extraños) instale los modulos otra vez con npm install pero no funcionaba, seguia corructo (la verdad no se si seria mi conexion de internet q es bastante mala). El caso es q localice este archivo en mi node modules y luego lo busque en github y copie el codigo de este en mi archivo. Y funciono. Sabes pq se pudo corromper este archivo? No es la primera vez q m pasa. Gracias x tu tiempo

Comment: Estas guardando tu proyecto en una unidad compartida con otros usuarios o de red? O quizas en una carpeta de Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox... etc.. que se sincroniza con tu servicio de almacenamiento? En el pasado he tenido casos de corrupcion y todos venian de ahi

Comment: No en realidad no tengo nada en ningun tipo de servicio en la nube. Podria ser algun tipo de virus?? Porque me paso algo realmente extraño. Cuando copie el codigo de github el que te comente arriba lo guarde en un txt por si acaso volvia a pasar y luego ese dia termine de trabajar y apague la pc y cuando vuelvo a trabajar al otro dia este archivo txt estaba corrupto exactamente igual (con los mismos caracteres raros exactos) que el archivo es.regexp.exec.js. Luego de esto ya no ha pasado mas. Tambien no me he vuelto a conectar a internet desde esa pc.